# postgres function SELECT INTO

Tags: postgresql, function

```
SELECT u.email, u.id
INTO useremail1, userid1
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.mobilestatus='1'
    AND u.emailstaus='1'
    AND u.user_from='2'
```

showing error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 8:         select INTO
>   u.email, u.id  useremail1, userid1 from ...

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
SQL state: 42601

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.caluserapp()
RETURNS TABLE( userid1 integer
             , useremail1 character varying
             , usermobile1 integer
             , userfrom1 integer
             , mobilestatus1 integer
             , emailstatus1 character varying
             , nocid1 character varying
             , nocuniqueid1 character varying
             , noctype1 integer
             )
AS $$
DECLARE
    i         integer;
    distrow   text;
    resultout text;
BEGIN
    FOR distrow IN
        SELECT u.email
             , u.id
        INTO useremail1, userid1
        FROM users AS u
        WHERE u.mobilestatus='1'
            AND u.emailstaus='1'
            AND u.user_from='2'
    LOOP 
        resultout:=(select email from officers where id=id );
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: showing error ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 8: select INTO u.email, u.id useremail1, userid1 from ... ^ ********** Error **********

Comment: Your function makes no sense as it stands. What are you doing with `i` and `resultout`? `useremail1` and `userid1` need to be declared in the `DECLARE` block for you to be able to use `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: can u plz modifed the code and send me the correct code, as i am new to postgres function

Comment: Not really. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. The error you have doesn't match the query you posted either. The error shows a `SELECT INTO x,y,z` with no columns after the `SELECT`. The syntax is `SELECT a, b, c INTO x, y, z`. Where `x, y, z` are declared variables.

Comment: @AmitGupta : Give us enough information as to what the function should do and mention it clearly. People here don't want to scratch their heads to understand what is in your mind. Do add table definitions and sample data if possible so that it'll be easier for us to recreate your problem. Don't add additional information in the comments.Kindly [**Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56907016/edit) your question to do it.

Comment: The structure of your output table does not match anything you do inside the function. And what are you trying to accomplish with the loop? The assignment `resultout:=(select email from officers where id=id );` doesn't really make sense. You can easily integrate a string_agg()` into your main query and get rid of that loop completely. You should explain to us what the _underlying_ problem is you are trying to solve with that function.

Comment: i am totally new to postgres function...
i am just trying to fetch the set of records in for loop, but as i am feting the record and storing it into variables using into its showing me error...

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 12:         select email,id into useremail1,userid1 from users w...

unable to understand what syntactical error is their... so plz help in out in this...